# Time period between the use of dragon balls during Namek Saga

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball

Remember when Vegeta came to the Earth for the first time. At that time the dragon balls were used to bring Goku back to life. During the battle Piccolo died and later Bulma and the rest go the planet Namek to use their dragon balls. Later when Piccolo was revived using Namekian dragon balls and they became useless due to the death of Guru, the dragon balls of Earth were used to revive the Namekians.

So, how much time in the Earth days (or months) passed between the revival of Goku and the revival of Namekians?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Dragon Ball's timeline's wikia page](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Timeline):

1. **November 2nd, Age 762:** Goku is revived on November 2nd, Age 762 by the Earth Dragon Balls
2. **Age 762, December 24:** Every one killed by Frieza on planet Namek is revived by the Earth Dragon Balls

So (much) less than one year has passed between these two uses of Dragon Balls. I don't know if there is a canon explanation for this, but maybe the death and resurrection of Piccolo and Kami reset the Dragon Balls. This is the only explanation I could think off.